# What is the shatter coefficient / VC - dimension of some hypothesis set?

Tags: co.combinatorics, learning-theory

Let $H:=\{h:\mathbb{N}_0^n \rightarrow \{0,1\}| h(x_1,\cdots,x_n) = \mathbb{1}_0(\sum_{i\in I}{x_i}-\sum_{j \notin I}{x_j}) \text{ for some } I \subset \{1,\cdots,n\}\}$
where $\mathbb{1}$ is the indicator function.
How big is the shatter coefficient $s(H,m)$?

The shatter coefficient is defined as:
$s(H,m) = \max{\{|H(Y)|:|Y| = m , Y  \subset \mathbb{N}_0^n\}}$
where $H(Y) := \{ (h(y_1),\cdots,h(y_m)) \in \{0,1\}^m | y_i \in Y, h \in H\}$ for all $Y = \{y_1,\cdots,y_m\} \subset \mathbb{N}_0^n$

Answer (score 1):

Your $H$ is a sub-class of $n$-dimensional hyperplane separators; hence its VC-dimension is at most $n$. This would also follow from simple cardinality arguments, since there are $2^n$ subsets of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$.